# How do I turn all hyperlinks into "tap" on mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, html

On mobile, my backbone apps work really slow. More precisely, clicking a link is not the same as tapping in native apps. (clicking a link has a delay - try it)

In native apps, tapping is almost instantaneous.

Is there a way to register the hyperlinks as tap events (Jquery tap)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed Fix: How to Remove the 300ms Delay in jQuery Mobile Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477328/speed-fix-how-to-remove-the-300ms-delay-in-jquery-mobile-apps)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy that's JQuery mobile.

Comment: The issue at hand is unrelated to "jQuery Mobile", and if you read the question properly it makes no direct reference to the "jQuery Mobile" library.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, by default the .click event has a 300ms delay on touch devices.

To correct this it is easiest to use a library rather than to write the "un-delay" yourself. The one I use for all my projects is: https://github.com/filamentgroup/tappy

It's great! Let me know if you have any questions - but the documentation on that page is pretty clear.