# bind touchend to url's in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i've been searching all day long on how to removal the 300ms from my jquery mobile app but all the solutions haven't worked but out including `fastclick`. I read an article and discover i could bind `touchend` events to my links which will remove the 300ms delay and i want someone to help me do it. below is my html

```
 <Html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content"><a href="#page2">go to page2</a></div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content"><a href="#page">back to page1</a></div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed Fix: How to Remove the 300ms Delay in jQuery Mobile Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477328/speed-fix-how-to-remove-the-300ms-delay-in-jquery-mobile-apps)

Comment: i checked out that tutorial and it didn't work

Comment: in order to get help you need to do more than "it didn't work".